# How to use sinus and cosinus with residue

Tags: calculus, analysis, residue-calculus

I have this integral:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \dfrac{sin(x)}{x^2+6x+13} dx$$

I want to solve it with the residue theorem.

First I transformed it into complex numbers:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \dfrac{sin(z)}{z^2+6z+13} dz$$
We know: $$\sin(z) = \dfrac{e^{iz} - e^{-iz}}{2i} $$
So I can write: $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \dfrac{\dfrac{e^{iz} - e^{-iz}}{2i}}{z^2+6z+13} dz$$

Res_1 : $$\dfrac{e^{-4}(cos(3) - isin(3)) - e^4(cos(3) + isin(3))}{2i*8i}$$
Res_2 : $$\dfrac{e^{-4}(cos(3) + isin(3)) - e^4(cos(3) - isin(3))}{2i*-8i}$$

My result is:

$$\dfrac{(e^{-4} - e^4) \pi i cos(3)}{4}$$

Wolfram Alpha says:

$$\dfrac{\pi sin(3)}{2e^2}$$

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: You need to state what contour you use, and check what happens to your integrand on it.

Comment: Incorrect residue values , ReCalculate Singularity points . Also, no need to write $sinz$ in terms of $e^{iz}$ it will automatically even out in the end.